# How do I translate 自己已经将地级上品功法无相神功...?

Tags: translation

> 自己已经将地级上品功法无相神功，以及无相步，无相指和无相剑法传授给了他，不知道他如今修炼的如何？

This is what Google says:

> He has already taught him the skills at the prefecture level, and there is no step by step, no point and no swordsmanship. He does not know how he is practicing now.

I know the author is talking about the name of a cultivation method. What would it be called? How would this passage be translated as?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%97%A0%E7%9B%B8%E7%A5%9E%E5%8A%9F/776252?fr=aladdin). "无相神功" comes from a novel about an insuperable form of Kungfu. This is not very serious literature.

将 = 把
I set 无相 = formless, but maybe there are better translations.

自己已经将地级上品功法无相神功，
I already （将） [taught him 传授给了他] the earth-level best kungfu method "formless miracle" 
(无相神功 = a kind of kungfu, just a name, don't translate)"

以及无相步，
also the "formless step" = (a kind of kungfu, just a name, don't translate)

无相指和无相剑法 （go to 将）[传授给了他]，
the "formless finger" (just a name, don't translate)  and "formless sword" method"

不知道他如今修炼的如何？
don't know what his kungfu is like now.

不要打我哦！

Answer (score 0):

if you are try to learning Chinese, don't start from these....definitely a bad sample

delete[地级上品功法无相神功，以及无相步，无相指和无相剑法]part, it's all proper noun, skill name, can't be translate

I've been taught him all the skill, I wondering how he trained today?